# batch/bat - Move function with as input a text file with list of directories

Tags: list, function, directory, move

I'm writing a bat file and would like to add a move function. The idea is that I have a .txt file with on each line a relative path\file.

So for instance - and this is just a random example:

> Data\English\caust00.tga
>
> Data\English\Specific\caust01.tga
>
> Data\caust00.tga
>
> Data\caust00

At the moment I only have a delete function, which is simple because it doesn't require an additional set with variables. (Obviously, there are more files inside the "Data" otherwise I'd just move the entire folder).

Say the 4 lines above are saved in Test.txt, it would only be this line:

> for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Test.txt) do del "%%A"

to delete all 4 files. Now this is nice, but I want to implement a move function: i.e. that it creates a new folder, say "Temp1" with inside it - this depends on the content of "Test.txt":

> Data\English\caust00.tga
>
> Data\English\Specific\caust01.tga
>
> Data\caust00.tga
>
> Data\caust00

I hope you didn't get lost already. I'd love to receive some advice, because I'm pretty much clueless how to go about it.

**EDIT**:
So, I have a folder called "Data" with a lot of subfolders and files inside it.
I also have a text file with this content:

> Data\Movie\caust00.tga
>
> Data\Movie\caust01.tga
>
> Data\caust02.tga
>
> Data\caust03.tga
>
> Data\WaterPlane\SCCSpyDrone.ani
>
> Data\WaterPlane\SCCStop.ani
>
> Data\WaterPlane\SCCTimedChg.ani

Now I want to implement a move function that moves these files to a new folder "Test" so that we get this:

> Test\Data\Movie\caust00.tga
>
> Test\Data\Movie\caust01.tga
>
> Test\Data\caust02.tga
>
> Test\Data\caust03.tga
>
> Test\Data\WaterPlane\SCCSpyDrone.ani
>
> Test\Data\WaterPlane\SCCStop.ani
>
> Test\Data\WaterPlane\SCCTimedChg.ani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mkdir C:\DestFolder\
move C:\SourceFolder\*.* C:\DestFolder\
```

This will move all files from `SourceFolder` to `DestFolder`

**EDIT:**

What if you do something like this instead:

If you have the following folder structure:

```
    SourceFolder
     |-move.bat
     |-FilesToMove.txt
     |-1.txt
     |-2
       |-2.txt
```

Where `FilesToMove.txt` contains:

```
1.txt 
2\2.txt
```

and `move.bat` looks like this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (FilesToMove.txt) do call:moveFunc %%A C:\DestFolder\

:moveFunc
md %2\%1\..\ 2> nul
move %1 %2\%1
```

When you now run `move.bat`, `1.txt` and `2\2.txt` will be moved to `C:\DestFolder`. Does this do what you need?

Comment: "(Obviously, there are more files inside the "Data" otherwise I'd just move the entire folder)." Please read carefully.

Comment: I know, but I thought I'd try and nudge you in the right direction instead of giving you the answer because discovering the solution for yourself is much more satisfying don't you think? :)
Anyways, this should do what you want:

mkdir F:\Programs\MoveBatScript\DestFolder\

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Test.txt) do move "%%A" F:\Programs\MoveBatScript\DestFolder\


NOTE: I'm not able to put those lines in code format for some strange reason.

Comment: mkdir "Temp1" 

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Test.txt) do move "%%A" "Temp1"  
  
  This only puts all of them inside the Temp1 folder, not inside the "Data" and "Data\English" folders - and hence files that have the same name gets overwritten.

Comment: Martin Rindarøy - to your edited answer. Even if this was going to work, the files inside your "move.bat" are not variables; i.e. if I were to have files with other names this wouldn't work + my text file with directories could be exhaustingly long.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; Did you not want a .bat file that moves files from a SourceFolder to a DestinationFolder, where the individual files to be moved are specified in a .txt file?

Also, what do you mean by: "not variables"? Are you thinking about the "FilesToMove.txt" and "C:\DestFolder\" entries? I'm sure you are able to edit the script to make it parametric in those values.

Comment: "a .bat file that moves files from a SourceFolder to a DestinationFolder, where the individual files to be moved are specified in a .txt file?"
Yes, but the where the files should be inside the "DestinationFolder" depends on the relative path stored at each line in the .txt file. Is that clear enough?

Comment: How is this batch script not achieving that? Can you give me a concrete example? When 1.txt and 2.txt are moved from SourceFolder and DestFolder, the folder structure is kept across the move.

Comment: You're right, your latest bat does achieve this indeed. How would you edit list of directories to the appropriate form as under ":moveFunc" ? Maybe this is simple, but I fail to see it. I.E. How do I "transform" a list of directories into this system of make dirs and moves? Do you get what I mean?

Comment: No sorry, I do not understand :P What is it that you want to achieve? A concrete example would be helpful :)

Comment: Lemme get back at you in a few minutes this seems to be working already lol.

Comment: I wonder, why does adding pause after the move command interfere with the process? I suppose it's to do with the "call" but how can I continue with my bat file? :P I can only continue with the rest of my bat file if I call these lines of code from a separate bat file. I don't really like that.

Comment: Anyway it seems to work perfectly so far. I'll do some more testing but I'll just accept your answer. Great work, thank you a lot. It was so simple in fact :) If I find anything odd (e.g. bugs or w/e) I'll report them here.

Comment: I had a pause function in there for debugging purposes but you can just remove them. The latest version of `move.bat` shown in my edited original post no longer has this pause function.

Comment: Well, I figured I should put the move function at the end of my bat file as some sort of subroutine. So it's integrated in my bat file. Thanks again. I hope you gain some points for this from other users. Anyway, I'm still not sure what you did there (the move function itself, that is), could you be so kind to explain it? Yeah, I may be writing a bat file but I've still a lot to learn ;)